# Can I put a bounty on a CW question?

Tags: support, bounties, community-wiki

Can I put a bounty on a community wiki question? While I haven't found any information *eliminating* this possibility, I have also not found a *confirmation* answer. Given the special nature of CW questions, I'd like to make sure that bountifiability doesn't die with communitywikification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Just curious, is the information here still current?

Comment: @Neil Yes, it is, even if the bounty system has changed a bit since then.

Comment: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) does indeed contain the answer, under "_How does Community Wiki mode affect bounties?_".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, whether or not the question is Community Wiki makes no difference to the bounty system.

Comment: So you can gain rep from "winning" a CW question? That almost seems a little bit of a contradiction.

Comment: Not really. There will only ever be 1 accepted answer. I think of it like accepting an answer is O(1) and voting an answer up is O(n).

Comment: I have received an answered to one of my questions but in the meantime the answered got marked as CW. I would like to start and award a bounty, but I can't seem to be able to start a bounty, the button is missing. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

> Yes

Further to this, what happens when multiple users contribute to one post?

I assume it gets awarded to the person who originally posted the answer, which seems a little unfair if someone else contributes to the answer (which is hte idea of CWiki..), but splitting the bounty between contributors would be abuse-prone (people doing meaningless edits just before the bounty is awarded etc)

Comment: While it is a legitimate concern, I think that it's more theoretical than practical, as I have a hard time coming up with a time that this happened. Usually if someone is going to add a lot of content to a question, they add their own answer rather than editing another one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you even gain rep from an accepted answer of a Community Wiki question (I can't remember off the top of my head). If you can gain rep from a correct answer (which I want to say is not the case), then I would suspect you should be able to set a bounty...

But I do not believe that is true. I believe setting a rep on a bounty (if it were in fact possible) would be more like throwing away rep than anything else.

Comment: Yes, if you post an answer as CW and it's accepted, you get +15. Also, the bounty works as it should regardless of CW status.

Comment: Interesting       .

Comment: Huh. I thought CW meant that you would never get any rep from the answer; I guess I don't participate in CW questions often enough to have found out.

Answer (score 0):

It's happened. For example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082603/java-code-examples-for-tutoring)

Yet the FAQ seems wrong on this point:

> Of course, bounty awards, like all accepted answers, are immune to the daily reputation cap and community wiki mode.

Comment: That quote is correct: bounty awards and accepted answers are *immune* to community wiki mode, meaning that wiki has no effect at all on Rep earned in those two ways.

Comment: Ah - I thought it meant that such posts were immune from being turned into community wiki mode. How about a change of wording then?