# Can I reward contributions to a community wiki?

Tags: support, bounties, community-wiki

I am basically [looking for some non-existent documentation on using RabbitVCS for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891374/how-do-i-use-rabbitvcs-for-git). The question isn't eligible for a bounty yet. I think the most sensible approach would be a single community wiki answer with a list of git operations and equivalent RabbitVCS actions that grows over time.

It is not clear to me from [these answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2438/can-i-put-a-bounty-on-a-community-wiki-question) what would happen to the bounty if I assigned it.

Is there any way I can reward contributions to such an answer?

Comment: What not clear? *Bounties are not affected by community wiki mode. When you award a bounty to an answer marked community wiki, the reputation bonus will be awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Sha Dow's comment (above) the bounty is awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer. In other words, no, I cannot reward other contributions to a community wiki answer. I'll have to rely on good intentions :)

Comment: Well, if you think that someone added outstanding information and deserve a "prize" then, assuming it can be considered new answer, ask him/her to post as new answer and give the bounty.

Comment: that's good idea :)